# SCSS Referencing a Particular Instance of an Element

Tags: html, css, variables, sass, scss-lint

**Very** new to Scss/Sass Elsewhere in my mod.scss file, have coded the style of `Ul > li` that I reuse quite frequently.  However, in another mod.scss file, I need a change this code for a single particular instance.

Is it possible to essentially create an if-like statement that says: "If a UL/LI tag appears UNDER the `.content-section` class, take on behaviors X,Y and z"?

```
.content-section
{
    margin: 40px 0px;

    & .siteTitleText 
    {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    & .headers
    {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    img
    {
        margin: 30px 0px;
    }

    *ul*

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content-section vendors">
    <p class="headers">Modules, partials, and vendor</p>
    <p class="bodyText">As you can see this divides my project into three basic types of files. Modules, partials, and vendored stylesheets.</p>
    <ul>
        <li class="bodyText">The modules directory is reserved for Sass code that doesn't cause Sass to actually output CSS. Things like mixin declarations, functions, and variables.</li>

        <li class="bodyText">The partials directory is where the meat of my CSS is constructed. A lot of folks like to break their stylesheets into header, content, sidebar, and footer components (and a few others). As I'm more of a SMACSS guy myself, I like to break things down into much finer categories (typography, buttons, textboxes, selectboxes, etc…).</li>

        <li class="bodyText"></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also share your HTML structure?

Comment: Absolutely, I'll edit the post

Comment: Does "under" mean descendant of `.content-section' or physically beneath on the page layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `+` in your code to select the *next match below your closing tag*.
Simply nest the tags if you wish to select the *child* tag inside your `.content-section`.

Reference: [w3 documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

```
.content-section {
    margin: 40px 0px;

    & .siteTitleText {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    & .headers {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    img {
        margin: 30px 0px;
    }

    ul, li { // If .content-section has a child named ul or li, do this:
        margin: 100px;
    }
}
```

Comment: My understanding of the OP is that they mean when the `ul` is a child of `.content-section` not a sibling.

Comment: It's a bit unclear though, let's ask @TheodoreSteiner himself.

Comment: Hi All, I am very sorry, yes I mean a child of

Comment: Removing the + should then work, i'm on the move so I cant edit the post

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner Updated :).